# Is there a way to handle host restart for CRON task if the restart frequency is extremely low about once-twice per year?

Tags: centos, cron, host, job-scheduler

As mentioned in another question here: [Job scheduling using crontab, what will happen when computer is shutdown during that time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52335/job-scheduling-using-crontab-what-will-happen-when-computer-is-shutdown-during) that *Cron* jobs will not work during shutdown/restart case and we can use *Anacron* for such situations

For my case, there are lots of *Cron* jobs scheduled and chances of host restart is minimal that is once-twice a year and the hosts are up and running for the rest of the time and changing from *Cron* to *Anacron* may not be necessary. My *cron* tasks are assigned on the CentOS machine. Is there a way out?

I'm new to *Cron* tool. Any idea in the right direction will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some nice alices for [man (5) crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab), one of them is "@reboot".

You can use it to have it run when the system is started, and then another job for the specific date perhaps?

```
@reboot <path to job>
0 5 1 6,12 0 <path to job>
```

This would run the job at reboot AND 05:00 month 6 and 12 on the first day of the month.

A more complicated solution would be to have the cronjob create a file when run, and then you could check for the existence of that file when you boot to see if it's needed to run again or not, say after X days has passed since the file was created, but I leave you to think about that depending on your need.

Comment: Thanks, have a look here as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/1053118/do-we-have-to-rewrite-the-mailto-after-each-cron-command

Comment: I got a 404 on that link.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated it to here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633725/do-we-have-to-rewrite-the-mailto-after-each-cron-command